# How to add multiple wp_editor in single page

Tags: wordpress, wp-editor

I tried to add multiple wp_editor() in single page and it shows, but when I tried to add media, the media button is not working and I added the option (drag_drop_upload to true) to wp_editor option to make drag and drop and its worked.

But when I drag and drop the image, all the images are inserting in the first wp_editor instance. Even I tried to drag and drop in second or third wp_editor, but it again displaying in the first editor.

Is there any solution to insert the media either by uploading or drag and drop to the particular wp_editor instance?

Thanks

Comment: Are you try to write your own plugin or it this just for your customers posts/pages in a custom layout/format? If second one, I would suggest ACF (https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) instead of coding something for/around this. If not, you should show some code.

Comment: You need to add unique id for each editor.

Comment: @Sascha : Am trying to integrate with plugin, though I have tried with ACF by using its shortcode, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: @lolka_bolka: Yes I have added two different id for the wp_editor, like wp_editor('editor1','editor1',array('drag_drop_upload'=>true); and wp_editor('editor2','editor2',array('drag_drop_upload'=>true)

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to add multiple instances of wp_editor is 're-initialization' of the plugin for newly created element!

```
tinymce.init({ selector: '#' + editor_id});
```

Once you created new element just initialize the **tinymce** for that element.

Hope this helps some one.